# Regular expression to remove last word in a string

Tags: java

I have a string like this: "87 CAMBRIDGE PARK DR". I have used the below regular expression to remove the last word "DR", but it also removes the word "PARK"...

Below is my code...

```
String regex = "[ ](?:dr|vi|tes)\\b\\.?"; /* Regular expression format */

String inputString ="87 CAMBRIDGE PARK DR"; /* Input string */

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
inputString = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

Now the output is "87 CAMBRIDGE"..

But I need the output as "87 CAMBRIDGE PARK".

Answer (score 2):

Try the below regular expression:

```
String inputString ="87 CAMBRIDGE PARK DR";
System.out.println(inputString.replaceAll("\\w+$", ""));
```

Output:

87 CAMBRIDGE PARK

**Breaking down the above regular expression:**

```
"\\w+$"
```

-checks if end of the line is followed by several word characters.

Also, if you are sure your *last* word would only be capital (block) letters.

```
System.out.println(inputString.replaceAll("[A-Z]+$", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it as follows:

```
String inputString ="87 CAMBRIDGE PARK DR"; /* Input string */
System.out.println(inputString.replaceFirst("\\s+\\w+$", ""));
```

Regular expression understanding

```
\s+  : one or more white space characters

\w+  : one or more alpha-numerics

$    : the end of the input
```

One more way is as follows:

```
String inputString ="87 CAMBRIDGE PARK DR"; /* Input string */
inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.lastIndexOf(" ")) + "";
```